# NSTimer speeds up after UI activity

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6, nsurlconnection, nstimer

I make an asynchronous http request using `NSURLConnection` every 11 seconds using a `NSTimer`. 
The `NSTimer` runs on the main run loop. The request has a timeout of 10 seconds. 
The `NSTimer` works well until I increase UI activity on the app (like tapping on `UIButtons`, dismissing `UIAlertViews` frequently).

After this the `NSTimer` speeds up and runs like a while loop without any delays. This creates a lot of problems in the app as I can't make proper handling of the connection responses.

Comment: It speeds up temporarily or permanently?

Comment: It speeds up permanently thereafter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are declaring an NSTimer inside your button action... now every time this button is pressed the NSTimer interval is compiled onto its previous interval and the result is that it gets called twice as often... the next time it's twice as often than the previous twice as often.... etc.

The best way to do it is define the NSTimer in the .h file and then every time you have code in your .m file to call it first check if it's already there and if so invalidate and release it.

```
  if(myTimer){
        [myTimer invalidate];
        [myTimer release]; 
  }
  myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timeInterval) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: I've had this problem in many of my apps, I just now found the root of the problem when you mentioned "UI Activity" I feel quite foolish now haha :o) It seems so obvious.